# connect to oracle 11g with asp.net my machine configuration is 64 bit windows 8 and visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, oracle11g

pls tell me how to connect to oracle database 11g with asp.net my machine configuration is 64 bit windows 8 and visual studio 2013. I am working with sql server but new to oracle 
pls help me 
I am really stuck
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/database/article.php/c8477/Connecting-to-an-Oracle-Database-Using-ASPNETmdashA-StepbyStep-Tutorial.htm)

The above link might be useful

```
public DataTable myDataTable(string SQL, string ConnStr)
{
    OracleConnection cn = default(OracleConnection);
    DataSet dsTemp = null;
    OracleDataAdapter dsCmd = default(OracleDataAdapter);

    cn = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);
    cn.Open();

    dsCmd = new OracleDataAdapter(SQL, cn);
    dsTemp = new DataSet();
    dsCmd.Fill(dsTemp, "myQuery");
    cn.Close();
    return dsTemp.Tables[0];
}
```